# Is there a better way to do the following XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am learning XSLT and doing some simple examples to get a better taste of it. I want to transform a XML file to html via XSLT. Here is my XML:

```
<structure>
    <part class="H1" id="h11"/>
    <part class="H2" id="h21"/>
    <part class="H3" id="h31"/>
    <part class="H4" id="h41"/>
    <part class="H5" id="h51"/>
    <part class="H6" id="h61"/>
</structure>
<style>
    <property part-name="h11" name="text">This is a h1 heading</property>
    <property part-name="h21" name="text">This is a h2 heading</property>
    <property part-name="h31" name="text">This is a h3 heading</property>
    <property part-name="h41" name="text">This is a h4 heading</property>
    <property part-name="h51" name="text">This is a h5 heading</property>
    <property part-name="h61" name="text">This is a h6 heading</property>
</style>
```

And here is my simple XLST:

```
<xsl:key name="headings" match="property[@name='text']" use="@part-name"/>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H1']">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:key name="headings" match="property[@name='text']" use="@part-name"/>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H2']">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h2>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H3']">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h3>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H4']">
    <h4>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h4>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H5']">
    <h5>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h5>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="part[@class='H6']">
    <h6>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </h6>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, it is very verbose and repetitive. Is there a way via some XPath expression to make it shorter and actually do the job in a better way? Perhaps, something like a regEx? 
Another way I can think of is with the use of `<xsl:if>` and have the whole thing inside one single template, but that's not much of an improvement IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="part[starts-with(@class, 'H')]">
    <xsl:element name="h{translate(@class, 'H', '')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('headings', @id)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great! that's actually what I am looking for! Just another thing, in case I have another `part` whose `class='Header'` for instance, it will be transformed to `<header>`. Is it possible to say in the match rule to expect an integer after the `'H'` so that this works only with heading elements and not with anything else?

Comment: There are ways, with XSLT 2.0 you can use regular expression matching e.g. `<xsl:template match="part[matches(@class, '^H[0-9]+$')]>`. With XSLT 1.0 if you know there are only `H1` to `H6` elements I might be tempted to list them e.g. `match="part[@class = 'H1' or @class = 'H2' or ...]"` although you could also do something like `match="part[substring(@class, 1, 1) = 'H' and number(substring(@class, 2)) = number(substring(@class, 2))]"` which should do the check, although is not very readable and not necessarily clear to readers of the code without some comment.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!